# Sort a vector of objects by a member of map in this vector

Tags: algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

I have a very simple question i guess but...
I have to sort a vector by it's own member, but I can not.

This is my function for filling the vector with objects from another vector.
I have to sort the vector SortDealers by specific product but I don't know how to send the name of the Stock to my overloading operator<

```
void CShop::sortVector(const CStock& s1)
{
    vector<CDealer> SortDealers;
    vector<CDealer* >::iterator it = Dealers.begin();
    while (it != Dealers.end())
    {
        if ((*(*it)).ComapareNameProducts(s1))
        {
            SortDealers.push_back(*(*it));
        }
        it++;

    }
    sort(SortDealers.begin(), SortDealers.end());
    copy(SortDealers.begin(), SortDealers.end(), ostream_iterator<CDealer>(cout, "\n"));
}
```

this is overloading operator<:
I have to sort by unsigned member of the map.

```
bool CDealer::operator<(const CDealer & o1)
{
    unsigned res1 = 0;
    unsigned res2= 0;
    map<const CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>::const_iterator it = Stock.begin();
    map<const CStock, pair<unsigned, double>>::const_iterator iter = o1.Stock.begin();
    while (it != Stock.end())
    {
        res1 += it->second.first;
        it++;
    }
    while (iter != o1.Stock.end())
    {
        res2 += iter->second.first;
        iter++;
    }
    return (res1 < res2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use functor:

```
class less_than
{
    const string stockname;
    public:
    less_than(string s) : stockname(s) {}
    inline bool operator() const (const CDealer& a, const CDealer& b)
    {
        // use stockname here
    }
};

sort(SortDealers.begin(), SortDealers.end(), less_than("name"));
```

Also you can use lambda expression providing stock name in its capture.

- [Related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26205551/312896)