# What does "state" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, state, functor

When I was looking for explanations of C++ functor, I saw the following statement,
"There are a couple of nice things about functors. One is that unlike regular functions, they can contain state."

Could anybody explain to me what "state" means in C++? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you link to the statement, or provide context of the statement? "State" usually means some kind of memory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ functor advantage - holding the state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204980/c-functor-advantage-holding-the-state)

Comment: http://imalogic.com/blog/2017/05/12/c-functor/ this looks like where the statement came from.

Comment: In computer science, "state" refers to information or data that depends on history of the system.   In C++, that concept of state is represented using variables or objects that can represent one or more distinct values that have meaning to some part of the program.   So a variable or struct member of type `int` represents some state - for example, changing the value of that `int` represents a change of state (e.g. it can affect code that uses it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does “state” mean ...

The word has multiple meanings and contextual subtleties.

Here is a general definition for the word from a [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/state):

> a condition or way of being that exists at a particular time

---

> ... in C++?

There is no C++ specific meaning for the word as far as I know. It is not something specified by the language. The meaning is same as in programming or computer science in general.

Here is a computer science specific [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science)):

> In information technology and computer science, a system is described as stateful if it is designed to remember preceding events or user interactions; the remembered information is called the state of the system.

The state of a C++ program consists primarily of the representation of objects.

---

> "There are a couple of nice things about functors. One is that unlike regular functions, they can contain state."

While this is "true enough" in practice, it is a simplification. Technically regular functions can "contain" *global* state. But that is probably ignored by the author of that quote since global state is problematic and something that should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are actually asking what it means *in this context*:

It means that a functor (i.e. an instance of a class implementing the `()` operator) can store and access information that is related to its particular instance.

A regular function can only access whatever parameters are passed into it, plus global variables etc.

Example with a functor however:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Counter {
    int operator()() { return ++count; }

  private:
    int count = 0;
};

Counter count1;
Counter count2;

std::cout << count1() << std::endl; // 1
std::cout << count1() << std::endl; // 2
std::cout << count1() << std::endl; // 3

std::cout << count2() << std::endl; // 1
std::cout << count2() << std::endl; // 2
std::cout << count2() << std::endl; // 3

std::cout << count1() << std::endl; // 4
std::cout << count2() << std::endl; // 4
```

Here, the actual count is encapsulated in the functor instance - it is the functor's *state*.